# Prevent Outlook Adding unwanted Signatures repeatedly in VBA

Tags: vba, email, ms-word, outlook

I want to prevent Outlook from Appending a Signature to any newly opened Outlook MailItem.  When using `Outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(TemplateName)` a default signature is automatically appended to the new MailItem.  When working with multiple accounts attached to the Outlook Client that Signature is often unwanted, or is simply the wrong one.  To make things worse, many Outlook Methods append further duplicate copies of the unwanted signature.  It is possible to  wind up with a whole slew of them attached.

When opening a Template, the Signature appended is the Default for the Account that was active when TemplateName was *saved*.  It is *not* the Default for the currently active Account.  One idea is to temporarily switch off the signature for the relevant Account and add the required Signature directly as this would be a fairly simple fix for the problem.  **Is there a way to switch off the signature for a specific account?  I can't find one.**

The signature for the Default account **can** be Switched off by setting
`appWd.EmailOptions.EmailSignature.NewMessageSignature = vbNullString` and it can also be restored later but this does not help.  An idea for a possible workaround was to programattically change the default account, switch off the default account's signature, open the required TemplateName and then restore everything back to the original state.  However, it doesn't work because:

- a) I can't find a way to switch the Default Account programattically.  It seems that this is only possible by clicking in the User Interface.
- b) And it would make no difference, anyway, because the Signature for the
  Account that saved TemplateName would be used despite the change.

Underlying this requirement is the fact that I need to merge parts of existing MailItems in Outlook using VBA.  The objective is to merge parts of multiple items into a new MailItem for onward distribution to a mail list.  The merging all works effectively using `MailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor` and I have sorted out the issues related to attachments and embedded pictures but the multiple Signatures, which would seem to be such a simple matter in comparison, are causing a problem.  Is there way to switch them off? Getting rid of them in the WordEditor or in the HTML would be very difficult as Signatures have arbitrary structures.

Comment: Did you try using SendUsingAccount to switch the account you want to send from? I could be wrong, but doesn't the signature get generated based on the account you are sending from?

Comment: I did try.  It does not work, at least not on a system with both POP3 and Exchange accounts attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but something like this should work.

Basically, store the HTML of the email prior to displaying, then compare it after it's shown and update the HTML if it's different.

```
Public Sub OutlookTest()
    Dim Outlook             As Object
    Dim MyTemplateItem      As Object
    Dim OriginalBody        As String

    Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set MyTemplateItem = Outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\SomePath\Example.oft")

    OriginalBody = MyTemplateItem.HTMLBody
    MyTemplateItem.Display

    If MyTemplateItem.HTMLBody <> OriginalBody Then MyTemplateItem.HTMLBody = OriginalBody
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice idea.  As you say, not very elegant, possibly fairly expensive on CPU and requiring both the HTMLbody (as text) and the .oft to be saved for the duration but it would work, I think.  So far, my workaround during testing has been to simply find and delete the 'usual suspect' signature from the body before it is sent.  Your method would do better than that.  Thanks.  I'll wait a bit before trying it, in the hope that someone knows how to switch off the problem at source rather than hack round it.

Comment: I'm with you, yeah I poked around a bit and I couldn't find much either. Maybe poke Dmitry Streblechenko, Dmitry knows lots re: Outlook :)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try to get his attention.  Hi, [Dimitry streblechenko](http://stackoverflow.com/users/332059/dmitry-streblechenko).  In my thread, [Ryan Wildry](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4839827/ryan-wildry) has suggested bringing this question to your notice.  The core of it is: 'Is it possible in VBA code to switch off the Default signature for an arbitrary Outlook Account?'

Comment: I'm now using [Ryan Wildry's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4839827/ryan-wildry) solution as the only one that works at all.  It was pretty complicated to implement.  It seems to be important to use `MailItem.Display` after making any edits to the Document created with `Set Doc = MailItem,.GetInspector.WordEditor` .  I actively don't want to see it displayed, but without the `.Display` the Signature in the original template is automatically changed to the Session default.  Sadly, [Dimitry streblechenko](http://stackoverflow.com/users/332059/dmitry-streblechenko) didn't pick up on this!